# Drawing Lines in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am relatively new to Tikz and am trying to draw a diagram with lines in it. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0.9) -- (3.0,0.9) -- (3.0,-0.9) -- (0,-0.9) -- (0,0.9);
\draw (1.0,-0.9) -- (1.0,0.9);
\draw (2.0,-0.9) -- (2.0,0.9);
\path (1.1,0.6) node (p9) {};
\path (1.1,0.2) node (p10) {};
\path (1.1,-0.2) node (p11) {};
\path (1.1,-0.6) node (p12) {};
\path (1.9,0.6) node (p13) {};
\path (1.9,0.2) node (p14) {};
\path (1.9,-0.2) node (p15) {};
\path (1.9,-0.6) node (p16) {};
\path (2.1,0.6) node (p17) {};
\path (2.1,0.2) node (p18) {};
\path (2.1,-0.2) node (p19) {};
\path (2.1,-0.6) node (p20) {};
\path (2.9,0.6) node (p21) {};
\path (2.9,0.2) node (p22) {};
\path (2.9,-0.2) node (p23) {};
\path (2.9,-0.6) node (p24) {};
\draw  (p9) to [bend left=10] (p17);
\draw  (p10) to [bend left=10] (p18);
\draw  (p11) to [bend left=10] (p19);
\draw  (p12) to [bend left=10] (p20);
\draw  (p13) to [bend right=10] (p21);
\draw  (p14) to [bend right=10] (p22);
\draw  (p15) to [bend right=10] (p23);
\draw  (p16) to [bend right=10] (p24);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

This results in the following output

[image]

Can anyone explain why the curved lines don't appear to be hitting the correct nodes?

**Edit:** To clarify the situation, the question was concerned with why the lines were not apparently reaching the centre of the nodes in question. Solutions to this have been addressed in the answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The curved lines hit the nodes but even empty nodes have a width and height. To show this the nodes in the second picture are drawn. Maybe you want to define `coordinate`s instead of `node`s like in the third picture:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  green!40!black,
  colored/.style={fill=#1!20,draw=#1!50!black!50}
]
\draw[help lines, step=0.5] (0,0)grid(2,1);
\path (0.5,0.5) node (p1) {};
\path (1,0.5) node (p2) {};
\draw (p1) to [bend left=10] (p2);
%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1.1cm]
\draw[help lines, step=0.5] (0,0)grid(2,1);
\path (0.5,0.5) node[colored=red] (p3) {};
\path (1,0.5) node[colored=blue] (p4) {};
\draw (p3) to [bend left=10] (p4);
\end{scope}

\draw[dotted](p1.east)--(p3.east)(p2.west)--(p4.west);
%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2.2cm]
\draw[help lines, step=0.5] (0,0)grid(2,1);
\path (0.5,0.5) coordinate (p5);
\path (1,0.5) coordinate (p6);
\draw (p5) to [bend left=10] (p6);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to place your tikz picture in a displayed math environment (i.e. remove the brackets \[ \]).

when you use "to", tikz will draw an edge connecting to the exterior boundary of your node (not drawn in your picture but still computed) compare:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw](x){};
\node[draw](y) at (2cm,0){};
\draw (x) to [bend left=10] (y);
\draw[red] (x.center) to [bend right=10] (y.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: edge to node boundary vs edge to center]

PS: Please try to actually produce a *minimal* working example and be more precise about what the problem is. I am not sure I understood what you are asking for. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment made by @Echsecutor, it's not clear what result you are aiming for. To illustrate that poster's point with your example, look at the difference in how the lines are drawn depending on how you specify the end point.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0.9) -- (3.0,0.9) -- (3.0,-0.9) -- (0,-0.9) -- (0,0.9);
\draw (1.0,-0.9) -- (1.0,0.9);
\draw (2.0,-0.9) -- (2.0,0.9);
\path (1.1,0.6) node (p9) {};
\path (1.1,0.2) node (p10) {};
\path (1.1,-0.2) node (p11) {};
\path (1.1,-0.6) node (p12) {};
\path (1.9,0.6) node (p13) {};
\path (1.9,0.2) node (p14) {};
\path (1.9,-0.2) node (p15) {};
\path (1.9,-0.6) node (p16) {};
\path (2.1,0.6) node (p17) {};
\path (2.1,0.2) node (p18) {};
\path (2.1,-0.2) node (p19) {};
\path (2.1,-0.6) node (p20) {};
\path (2.9,0.6) node (p21) {};
\path (2.9,0.2) node (p22) {};
\path (2.9,-0.2) node (p23) {};
\path (2.9,-0.6) node (p24) {};
\draw  (p9) to [bend left=10] (p17.center);
\draw  (p10) to [bend left=10] (p18.west);
\draw  (p11) to [bend left=10] (p19.east);
\draw  (p12) to [bend left=10] (p20);
\draw  (p13) to [bend right=10] (p21);
\draw  (p14) to [bend right=10] (p22);
\draw  (p15) to [bend right=10] (p23);
\draw  (p16) to [bend right=10] (p24);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

with result 
[image]